# TS2345: Argument of type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'

Tags: typescript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a chrome extension in typescript.

I have the following code, where I try to send a message to contentscript from the background script.

```
// background script 
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
   chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {action: "open_dialog_box"}, function(response) {
      console.log(response);
   });  
});
```

but typescript is giving the following error

```
ERROR in /Users/shobi/Projects/Chrome Extensions/src/js/background.ts(8,37)
      TS2345: Argument of type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

I tried converting the id to an integer using parseInt(), but still its not preventing the error.

Comment: `.id` is possibly undefined. Use a non-null assertion like `tabs[0].id!` or better yet, check in your code to make sure it isn't undefined.

Comment: Well. the non-null assertion trick worked. can you post an answer?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Chrome's tab `.id` is possibly undefined (because it's [defined as optional in the type definitions](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/7d616512eb210a0d1843adcfcce63a5c1fd734ba/types/chrome/index.d.ts#L5981)), which means when using `strictNullChecks` you have to either use a non-null assertion:

```
tabs[0].id!
```

Or write code to ensure that id is not null:

```
if (tabs[0].id) { // send message
```

Comment: Thanks for that non-null operator, really handy!

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing, but maybe typescript thinks that your tabs array could be empty (and thus not have an item at index [0]) - which is why it's type is inferred as number or undefined?

If this is the case, you should check that tabs[0] exists before trying to access the id property on it.

Comment: Even I think Its a problem with typescripts inference, because i found the solution just now. :)